# jquery geocomplete formatted address and street number

Tags: jquery, geocoding, street-address, formatted

I'm using this jQuery script:

http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/

When autocompletion is done, the formatted address will include the street number or not, depending on the user input but both entries will generate a success result.

Is it possible to never include the street number in the formatted address, even if it has been entered by the user during the completion?

As the street number is mandatory in my website and considering that this value is not mandatory during autocompletion, I will ask the user for it later anyway and, in the meantime, I have a hard time to manipulate formatted addresses that are not consistent (some have the number, others don't).

Ideally, I could get rid of the formatted address and consolidate my own format with "route", "locality" etc... but there are so many different addresses formats around the world that exist for some countries but not for others (states, provinces, regions,districts,...) that it is almost impossible to format something consistent on my own.

The formatted address **is perfect as it is** if only i could just get rid of the street number in order to add this information aside.

(Another acceptable solution would be to force the user to enter the street number or to generate a warning if this value is not entered. It would be fine with me too as long as the resulting formatted addresses always include the number or never do. Either way, I'm ok.
I'm just not ok with the inconsistency.

Thank you.